# Vector destructor causing program to crash in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, destructor

I have a `vector<vector<Person*>*>*` called groups (yes, I know about shared_ptr, but I can't use them in this context), and another one called partialGroups

Anyway, at the end of the method I delete all of the inner vector's, but not the people themselves, because I still want them to be valid, so here is the end of the code:

```
// Deal with remaining partial teams
vector<Person*> *unsortable;
groups->push_back(unsortable);
// Remaining people
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < people.size(); i++) {
    unsortable->push_back(people[i]);
}
// Remaining partial groups
for(unsigned int i = 0; i < partialGroups.size();i++) {
    for(unsigned int j = 0; j < partialGroups[i]->size(); j++) {
        unsortable->push_back(partialGroups[i]->at(j));
    }
    delete partialGroups[i];
}

return groups;
```

I then call the method with this line of code:

```
vector<vector<Person*>*> *currentMatch = sort(*people);
```

I can run gdb all th way to the return groups; statement, and looking at the data structure, it is just fine.  However, when I step out of the method, the program crashes, and the stack trace shows that it's crashing in the vector destructor itself.

What on earth could cause this?  It shouldn't be a problem with the Person destructor as the inner vector is of pointers to people.  Also, taking out the delete line does not make a difference.  (Yes, I know it would leave a memory leak, but it might have helped to diagnose the problem).

Thank you.

edit:  Also, the error is a sigabrt

Comment: Any reason not `std::vector<std::vector<Person*> >` ? No reason to have a pointer to a vector in a vector.

Comment: You really love pointers dontcha?

Comment: Could you post a complete test case that exhibits the problem?  Please still reduce the code length, but verify that it shows only problems you don't understand and is otherwise free of problems you would understand, like compiler errors.  Right off the bat, you current code above has UB using the uninitialized unsortable.

Comment: @PigBen, @billy, Well, I was moving stuff around a lot in the arrays, but at this point, I really don't care anymore, so I'm just changing it back to an array of objects themselves, thank you anyway.

Comment: @Fred, Well, I posted the whole thing because they were correlated, but I guess they may not have been.

Comment: @Leif: I don't understand: this *isn't* the whole thing, it obviously will not compile as-is.

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase that, by whole thing, I meant that I posted everything I posted because I thought that it was related to the problem.  And as Dan pointed out, I wasn't initializing unsortable.

Comment: Maybe the only reason that I was first with the right answer is that there's a tendency to look at the code and go, *wait... it's not a complete snippet. He **must** have initialized that pointer somewhere else, right?* It really does help to see a self-contained set of code.

Comment: "(yes, I know about shared_ptr, but I can't use them in this context)" Who cares about shared_ptr? :) unique_ptr is your friend.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this code snippet is accurate, you're doing all kinds of things with an uninitialized pointer, `unsortable`. I'm surprised it gets as far as the exit from the method.

Comment: Holy crap, wow I've been at this too long, thank you so very much, I believe that's the problem, thank you.